# jqgrid close dialog box when clicked outside

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This function opens a popup dialog box using jqgrid. But when clicked outside i.e. webpage behind it, the dialog box closes. How to control that from happening. I want the dialog box to show up until close event is triggered.

```
function popupSearch() {
    $("#GridTable").jqGrid('searchGrid', {
        recreateFilter: true,
        multipleSearch: true,
        multipleGroup: true,
        groupOps: [{ op: "AND", text: "and" }],
        closeOnEscape: false,
        closeAfterSearch: true,
        closeAfterReset: true,
        caption: "Advanced Search",
        Find: "Search",
        Reset: "Cancel",
        matchText: "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Find",
        rulesText: "&nbsp;matches",
        searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }
    });
}
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid? What you describe is an old bug in jqGrid which is fixed in free jqGrid fork, which I develop. I recommend you to change URLs to jqGrid to the URLs described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and to repeat your test. The problem should not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding overlay option.

```
overlay:0
```

Comment: The option don't make the searching dialog **modal**.

Comment: when i add the option it solves the problem. I am not sure about modal. Guess i Should have done more research before creating the question...

Comment: Modal means that all input (inclusive the click) outside of the dialog will be suppressed. The click outside of the dialog should be ignored instead of closing the dialog. Do you tried with free jqGrid 4.13.1? It's the fork of jqGrid which I develop starting which changing the licence agreement of the main fork of jqGrid, renaming it to Guriddo jqGrid JS and making the product commercial (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438), the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). The problem which you describe is a bug the old version of jqGrid. I fixed the bug in free jqGrid.